# Fugue with the greatest number of subjects?

Tags: fugue

I’ve been studying fugues recently and I came across the concept of a double and triple fugue.  This lead me to wonder:

Is anyone aware of a fugue with the greatest number of subjects?

Comment: I really like this question; I’m voting to close only because I think it's a better fit for musicfans.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, just so there's no confusion: you're asking about number of *subjects* as opposed to number of *voices*, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure it settles any bets, but see https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/92651/how-many-voices-lines-can-a-fugue-realistically-have

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting my money on Kaikhosru Shapurji Sorabji's (Wikipedia: [Sorabji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaikhosru_Shapurji_Sorabji)) *Opus clavicembalisticum* (1929-30). According the the Sorabji Resource Site ([homepage](https://roberge.mus.ulaval.ca/srs/index.htm)) it has [10 fugue subjects](https://roberge.mus.ulaval.ca/srs/05-varia.htm) (the list on the linked page can be sorted by number of subjects).

*However*, the fugues comprise separate sections of the piece, so perhaps that's cheating. In that case, I nominate *Études transcendantes* (1940–44) No. 33, which has 7 subjects, or his *Third Organ Symphony* (1949-53), which has 6.

Comment: "Symphony" is not "fugue".

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Neither is an Etude, but both can contain fugues, and both listed here do.